# Memory analysis for UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing some profiling over my application to check for possible memory leaks. My application is `TabMenu` based with subsequent `UINavigationController` for each tab. When I go deep in an `UINavigationController`, the memory curve is rising, which is normal. The problem is that when I go back in the Navigation (popping `ViewControllers`), the consumption goes down a little bit but not as I expect. Because what I expect is the memory to be about the same as when entering a certain level of the `UINavigationController` hierarchy, but it's not.

Is this normal? Does it mean that I have some memory leak?

Following is the specific piece of code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    NTM_Accommodation *accommodation = [self.resources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    UIViewController *controller = [[NT_DetailsAccommodationViewController alloc] initWithResource:accommodation];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];  
}
```

I'm using ARC.

Comment: Before you push a new view controller N inside the current view controller M, is N a local or global variable of M?

Comment: N is a variable declared and instantiated inside a function of M, same function that passes this variable to the UINavigationController. I updated my message to show an specific code with this situation. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see any memory leaks in the code you posted

Comment: In theory, everything alloced inside the NT_DetailsAccommodationViewController, should be dealloced once this controller is popped out from the Navigation. But memory shows it doesn't, if I push and pop many times the same controller, memory consumption keeps increasing

Comment: maybe you can check inside NT_DetailsAccommodationViewController, if there's any memory leak